# How to allow LISTAGG overflow into new record in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, overflow, listagg

I want to aggregate a list of strings together, but I know this list of strings will exceed the limit. This set of strings has an identifier associated with it. So a table might look like this

```
id | my_strings
______________
x1 | string{1}
x1 | string{2}
.
.
.
x1 | string{N}
x2 | string{1}
```

What I would love for a result is the following:

```
id | all_strings
------------------
x1 | string{1},...,string{M}
x1 | string{M+1},...,string{N}
x2 | string{1}
```

So essentially, if all the strings from 1 to N for the id x1 exceed the limit, it cuts it off at the largest possible M and then makes a new record also with x1 as the id where the "all_strings" column is the rest.

Is there anyway in standard Snowflake SQL code to achieve this? I know that the strings are never identical to one another and but the *length* of the strings is constant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can calculate the number of values where the cutoff occurs, you could limit the number of records allowed per `id` using a `HAVING` clause with a `ROW_NUMBER()` where the number is < whatever your limit number is....and then `UNION ALL` that to the same statement where the number is between limit and limit x 2...and so on.  Not very dynamic, although you could put that into a UDTF and make it more dynamic.

Comment: Given that you would need to loop over the values to find the cutoff point to use in LISTAGG anyway, it would be easier to construct the string(s) in the loop rather than use LISTAGG

Comment: Are the strings a fixed length, is there an easy way to work out upfront how many rows to cut it off at?

Comment: if you use a UDTF to act as the accumulator, edge trigger, you can do one pass of the data to bucket it, and then aggregate on that output in the next.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, in this case the strings are a fixed length and I know that number beforehand so I, in general, do not need this to be very dynamic.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I agree that this would also work. But the scenario for this is a very very large table (in the billions of rows) and so reducing the number of passes over the data is ideal.

Comment: You do understand Lukasz’s answer double processes that data just like mine?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim yes actually, realized that right after I commented. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add subgroup to determine max number of elements per group:

```
-- max 5 elements
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,  CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY str) / 5) AS grp
  FROM t
)
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(str, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) AS all_strings
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, grp
ORDER BY ID, all_strings;
```

For input:

```
CREATE TABLE  t(id INT, str TEXT);

INSERT INTO t(id, str)
VALUES (1,'string01'),(1,'string02'),(1,'string03'),(1,'string04'),(1,'string05'),
(1,'string06'),(1,'string07'),(1,'string08'),(1,'string09'),(1,'string10'),(1,'string11'),
(2,'string12'),(2,'string13'),(2,'string14'),(2,'string15'),(2,'string16'),
(2,'string17'),(2,'string18'),(2,'string19');
```

Output:

```
ID  ALL_STRINGS
1   string01,string02,string03,string04,string05
1   string06,string07,string08,string09,string10
1   string11
2   string12,string13,string14,string15,string16
2   string17,string18,string19
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you so much! The key to my problem is that the lengths of each string is fixed and I know the length of these beforehand. So I can calculate the number of max strings per field that will minimize the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

using a [Javascript user defined table function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions#basic-examples-illustrating-the-callback-functions):

**Change the `40` to the cutoff you want.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CHAR_SUM"(INS STRING)
    RETURNS TABLE (BUCKET FLOAT)
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS '{
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
      var nl = row.INS.length > 0 ? 
            (row.INS.length + (this.sum > 0 ? 1: 0)): 0;
      
      if(this.sum + nl > 40){ 
        this.bucket = this.bucket + 1;
        this.sum = 0;
      }
      
      this.sum = this.sum + nl;
      rowWriter.writeRow({BUCKET: this.bucket});
      
    },
    initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
     this.bucket = 0;
     this.sum = 0;
    }}';
```

then we can:

```
with data as ( 
    select 
        x.id,
        seq8() as seq,
        'string' || seq::text as str
    from table(generator(rowcount=>10))
    cross join (values ('x1'),('x2')) as x(id)
)
select *
from data, TABLE(char_sum(str) over (partition by id order by seq));
```

[image]

now we can to the aggregation, like so:

```
with data as ( 
    select 
        x.id,
        seq8() as seq,
        'string' || seq::text as str
    from table(generator(rowcount=>10))
    cross join (values ('x1'),('x2')) as x(id)
)
select 
    id,
    listagg(str, ',') within group (order by seq) as batch,
    length(batch) as qa
from data, TABLE(char_sum(str) over (partition by id order by seq))
group by 1, bucket
order by 1, bucket;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I agree that this would work, but I wanted to avoid any UDFs since in the scenario that I'm describing, pure SQL is just easier to manage.

Comment: The way you describe the problem, sounded like you wanted the densest packing possible, which is only available this way (for variable sized strings)